# Does Every Extreme Point Maximize Some Linear Functional

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, convex-geometry, convex-analysis, extreme-points

Let $L^2$ be the set of all square-integrable functions $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ and $S \subset L^2$ be a closed and convex subset of $L^2$ containing the function that is constant and equal to zero. Are there conditions that ensure that *every extreme point* $f^\star \in S$ maximizes some linear functional
$$
J(f^\star) \geq \sup_{f \in S} J(f)
$$
of the form
$$
J(f) = \int_0^1 f(t) h(t) dt \,.
$$
for some $h:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ with $h \in L^1$.

Comment: Do you assume that $f$ belongs to $L^2[0,1]$? Maybe a consideration of supporting hyperplane through $f^\star$ would help.

Comment: I think you want to assume $S$ is a set of **measurable** functions and $h$ is in $L^1$, otherwise it's not clear that $J(f)$ is well-defined.

Comment: Thanks a lot Skeeve and Robert, I adjusted the question. Skeeve could you maybe elaborate a little on the hyperplane idea?

Comment: @Peter I'm not claiming I know the answer, but one observation is that $J(f) = (f,h)$, where $(f,h)$ denotes the inner product in $L^2$. Hence $f^\star \in S$ maximises the functional $J$ if and only if $\{\phi \in L^2 : (\phi,h)\}$ is a [supporting hyperplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supporting_hyperplane) of $S$ through $f^\star$.

Comment: Is $S$ closed in $L^2$?

Comment: I would be happy to assume that $S$ is closed and added this as an assumption.

Comment: Since now the question is in the $L^2$ framework, it might be better to write $h\in L^2$ instead of $h\in L^1$, to ensure integrability of $fh$ (of course it follows from boundedness of $f$, but this is slightly implicit).

Comment: by the way in my previous comment there was a typo: it should read as *$f^\star \in S$ maximises the functional $J$ if and only if $\{\phi \in L^2 : (\phi, h) = (f^\star, h)\}$ is a supporting hyperplane of S through $f^\star$*.

Comment: It might also be helpful (but not necessary) if you describe more precisely what sort of conditions you are looking for (e.g. formulate your conjecture as some yes/no question).